# flutter equivalent to DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementFromPoint()

Tags: flutter

I am wondering what is the equivalent of the web api [DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) in flutter.

Specifically, I am wondering how I could figure out what is the leaf element/widget instance in a widget hierarchy, given an Offset.

For example, consider the following structure:

[image: layout description image]

For the **First Offset** marked with a dark circle, I would expect to get some sort of data that can help me figure out the offset is over Container.

For the **Second Offset** marked with a dark circle, I would expect the stack.

For the last one, it would be the positioned element.

### A bit of context

I'm exploring the implementation of a visual editor similar to FIGMA in Flutter. I have experience in implementing such a rendering system with web technologies.

I want to render a selection indicator or outline when a tap/click happens on each element. These elements are nested. Adding multiple nested event handlers triggers all of them. For example, mouse enter and mouse leave when moving the mouse over the Stack or Positioned element would trigger all the parent event handlers as well.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer to your exact question: No direct equivalent. Possible to implement but not advisable.

You could theoretically implement your own version of `elementFromPoint()` by looking at how [GestureBinding](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/86f9ab511e0aba55b067cf59f90a7000a16b1de8/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/binding.dart#L283) works in Flutter. That would be a deep dive for sure, and you might learn from it, but there is a simpler solution. Even if you implement your own method, then you would still need to resolve conflicts when more than 1 element is found - and this is something Flutter solves out of the box with the gesture arena.

I see that you expect the top-most or deepest child to be reported, something that you can obtain by using the `GestureDetector` widget. What you're looking for is making your gesture detectors **`opaque`**. A `GestureDetector` has a property called `behaviour` of type [HitTestBehaviour](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html). The default for it is `deferToChild`. Here are the possible values:

```
/// How to behave during hit tests.
enum HitTestBehavior {
  /// Targets that defer to their children receive events within their bounds
  /// only if one of their children is hit by the hit test.
  deferToChild,

  /// Opaque targets can be hit by hit tests, causing them to both receive
  /// events within their bounds and prevent targets visually behind them from
  /// also receiving events.
  opaque,

  /// Translucent targets both receive events within their bounds and permit
  /// targets visually behind them to also receive events.
  translucent,
}
```

#### What follows is slightly related, so consider it a deep dive in your use-case

Since you're going down this path: I also built a WYSIWYG design system, with selection indicators, handles for rotating, resizing, etc. and have one advice: Completely separate your design rendering from your gesture detectors and selection indicators.

I initially put the gesture detectors "around" the design elements - in your example, the gesture detectors would sit in between yellow / blue / green / red. The reason this is a bad idea is that it complicates a few things. In some cases I needed to create touch areas larger than the design elements themselves, in which case I needed to add padding and reposition the `GestureDetector` parents. In other cases the design elements would become fixed or locked and would not have a `GestureDetector` parent and Flutter would completely rebuild the contents of the layer since tree comparing got confused. It gets messy fast. So, stack these layers:

1. Design on bottom, no interactivity.
2. Selection indicators, resize / rotate handles. Still no interactivity
3. Gesture detectors for all design elements. If you're lucky, you know the exact size, position, rotation for the design elements you can simply use `Positioned`. If you have groups of design elements, then your gesture detectors also get grouped and transformed together. If you also have self-sizing design elements (like images), it gets a bit more complicated, but I got around my issues by adding the design element as an invisible child. The way I would do this now is by loading meta-data about the images and knowing them at build time (as opposed to waiting for images to load and produce layout changes).
4. Selection indicators + resize / rotate handles gesture detectors. They are top-most and also opaque, so they catch everything that hits them.

This setup then allows you to experiment more in the gesture department, it allows you to use colored boxes to debug and in general will make your life easier.

TLDR: Use `opaque` gesture detectors.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain things in detail. I will take a look at the gesture detector in more detail. 

I managed to get by with nested mouse event handlers and a data layer that keeps track of the last visited element, then decide which is the leaf element that is now being hovered. This works fine as well. 

Ideally, I would have liked programmatic control, as in the ability to "query" the system by sending and offset and receiving the Element that is related to that render object, but this will do to.